# passing the correct urls.py pattern

Tags: django

I have a button which allows me to add a new botany record, I can click on a 'details' button and to gets the correct record by the botany_id. e.g:

```
http://localhost:8000/botany/1/
http://localhost:8000/botany/2/
http://localhost:8000/botany/3/
```

In that view/html I have another button which adds a composition to a related table. It should resolve using `http://localhost:8000/botany/1/addcomposition/3/` but it tries `http://localhost:8000/botany/addcomposition/3/`. This suggests there is an issue in the urls.py which looks like this, I suspect its missing a pattern to account for the botany_id

```
url(r'^addcomposition/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.addcomposition, name='addcomposition'),
```

For clarity I also include the html

```
<a href="{% url 'addcomposition' pk=fraction.fraction_id %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">+ Composition +</a>
```

Comment: It is hard to guess without knowing your application structure (for example, the answer may be different depending on where you are including that url). That said, I would expect your URL to be something like `^botany/<botany_id>/addcomposition/<pk>/`

Answer (score 1):

if I pas a second variable through the html, e.g. `fk=botany.botany_id` , add `(?P<pk>\d+)/` after `r'^` then the expected `http://localhost:8000/botany/1/addcomposition/3/` is displayed.

Solution, html:

```
<a href="{% url 'addcomposition' fk=botany.botany_id pk=fraction.fraction_id %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">+ Composition +</a>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<fk>\d+)addcomposition/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.addcomposition, name='addcomposition'),
```